# how to display model list in listview c# windows application

Tags: c#, windows, algorithm

i searched this problem but i did not find the answer I wanted
i developing to C# Form Application.I have model on below and a model list

How can display to this model list on a ListView ?

```
public class Personals{

    public int PersonalId{ get; set; }
    public int PersonalNo{ get; set; }
    public string PersonalTelephone{ get; set; }
    public string PersonalAdress{ get; set; }
    public bool PersonalGender{ get; set; }
}
```

My modelList

```
List<Personals> personals = new List<Personals>(); 
//I populate this personal list in database with entity framework dbContext
ListView lvw = new ListView();
```

Comment: Where and how do you populate your personals list?

Comment: Model list in my database with entity framework dbContext.